# Multiple threads and blocking sockets

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a TCP server on Windows Server 2k8. This servers receives data, parses it and then sinks it on a database. I'm doing now some tests but the results surprises me.

The application is written in C++ and uses, directly, Winsocks and the Windows API. It creates a thread for each client connection. For each client it reads and parses the data, then insert it into the database.

Clients always connect in simultaneous chunks - ie. every once in a while about 5 (I control this parameter) clients will connect simultaneously and feed the server with data.

I've been timing both the reading-and-parsing and the database-related stages of each thread.

The first stage (reading-and-parsing) has a curious behavoir. The amount of time each thread takes is roughly equal to each thread but is also proportional to the number of threads connecting. The server is *not* CPU starved: it has 8 cores and always less than 8 threads are connected to it.

For example, with 3 simultaneous threads 100k rows (for each thread) will be read-and-parsed in about 4,5s. But with 5 threads it will take 9,1s on average!

A friend of mine suggested this scaling behavoir might be related to the fact I'm using blocking sockets. Is this right? If not, what might be the reason for this behavoir?

If it is, I'd be glad if someone can point me out good resources for understanding non blocking sockets on Windows.

**Edit**:

Each client thread reads a line (ie., all chars untils a '\n') from the socket, then parses it, then read again, until the parse fails or a terminator character is found. My readline routine is based on this:

http://www.cis.temple.edu/~ingargio/cis307/readings/snaderlib/readline.c

With static variables being declared as __declspec(thread).

The parsing, assuming from the non networking version, is efficient (about 2s for 100k rows). I assume therefore the problem is in the multhreaded/network version.

Comment: @servermanfail Posted a little more info =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your lines are ~120–150 characters long, you are actually **saturating the network!**

There's no issue with sockets. Simply transfering 3 times 100k lines, 150 bytes each, over a 100 Mbps line (1 take 10 bytes/byte to account for headers) will take... 4.5 s! There is no problem with sockets, blocking or otherwise. You've simply hit the limit of how much data you can feed it.

Comment: I've done some time measurements and yes, I think you're right. Taking the time for parsing data my current bottleneck is the network. Well, let's go back optimize the parser (onre more time) and upgrade the data link =)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that although you have one thread per client, Windows will not automatically ensure they all run on different cores. If some of them are running on the same core, it is possible (although unlikely) to have your server in a sort of CPU-starved state, with some cores at 100% load and others idle. There are simply no guarantees as to how the OS spreads the load (in the default case).

To explicitly assign threads to particular cores, you can use [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It may or may not be worth having a bit of a play around with this to see if it helps.

On the other hand, this *may* not have anything to do with it at all. YMMV.

Comment: Even though windows scheduler is not exactly excellent, I don't believe it's so bad to let perfectly usable cores idle when there are schedulable threads. So no, that's nonsense.

Comment: @Jan: agreed. I guess I didn't make it entirely clear, but it's just something to keep in mind - it's most likely *not* the issue. However, based on the evidence provided, it can't be discounted either. If the scheduler were perfect, there would be no need for `SetThreadAffinityMask` in the first place.

Comment: Actually the reason for `SetThreadAffinityMask` is for cases where you know limiting thread migration helps because the threads have large working sets and migrating them would be trashing the memory cache too much, which is something the scheduler can't correctly guess without a hint. It won't help too much to work around a bad scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Non-blocking sockets are only useful if you want one thread to service multiple connections. Using non-blocking sockets and a poll/select loop means that your thread does not sit idle while waiting for new connections.

In your case this is not an issue since there is only one connection per thread so there is no issue if your thread is waiting for input.

Which leads to your original questions of why things slow down when you have more connections. Without further information, the most likely culprit is that you are network limited: ie your network cannot feed your server data fast enough.

If you are interested in non-blocking sockets on Windows do a search on MSDN for OVERLAPPED APIs

Comment: Good idea, this might be true. I'm using a 100Mbps link, I'll test using the giga interface tomorrow and post back the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could be running into other threading related issues, like deadlocks/race conditions/false sharing, which could be destroying the performance.

Comment: There's no common data or resources between threads in the read-and-parse stage.